# How to read excel file column by column

Tags: excel, vba, autocad

I want to read excel file column by column.
but my code read data row by row.

```
On Error GoTo errhand
Set ws = oBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
 Set rngSize = ws.UsedRange

 Dim row As Range
        For Each row In rngSize.Rows
            Dim cell As Range
            For Each cell In row.Cells
                MsgBox cell.value
            Next cell
Next row
```

Comment: When you put "For Each row ..." why would you expect columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment `Rows` will give you the rows. And `Columns` will give you the columns

```
Dim col As Range
For Each col In rngSize.Columns
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In col.Cells
        MsgBox cell.Value
    Next cell
Next col
```

PS I replaced the variable name `row` by `col` for better readability

A second way would be to copy the values of the range into an array

```
Dim vDat As Variant
vDat = rngSize.Value
 
Dim i As Long, j As Long
 
For i = LBound(vDat, 2) To UBound(vDat, 2)
    For j = LBound(vDat, 1) To UBound(vDat, 1)
        MsgBox vDat(j, i)
    Next
Next
```

In case of an array this version would also be possible

```
Dim vDat As Variant, element As Variant
vDat = rngSize.Value

For Each element In vDat
    MsgBox element
Next
```